# What is the difference between uplink and downlink (JMeter)?

Tags: testing, load-balancer

I am trying to create a load test with JMeter, and what I want to do is to limit the bandwidth to 200mbit/second. I have two options, which are "Network Bandwidth Downlink" and "Network Bandwidth Uplink".

What is the difference between these, and which one is more suitable to change?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

in terms of server and client communications .
***based on stream or traffic***
traffic going from the server to the clients called  downstream , and from clients to server called upstream .
***based on device connections***
client is up linked to server and server is down linked to clients

Answer (score 1):

From your side:

Upplink is the traffic that you send to your ISP, request, and all the another stuff.

Downlink, by th other side, is traffic that you download, traffic from your ISP to you.

Answer (score 0):

From different perspectives I would say that Orlando's answer is good in relation to the general idea of the internet. Gadeliow's answer well describes the terms in reference to a server-client relationship.
(not giving my opinion on answers, giving credit where it's due.)

But some software tracks up/downlink in reference to the interface. So download would be incoming, and upload would be outgoing. I have a switch/router that tracks like that. such a headache.

For choosing up/downlink to test, you need to determine what your server is being used for. What kind of load do you want it to endure?
In every case I can think of though, the downlink **from** the server **to** the clients will be under more strain. Even a file server will be used to download hosted files more frequently than they are uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter runs on a standalone machine, separate from the application server you are testing (see [The JMeter FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterFAQ)).

"Network Bandwidth Downlink" site:wiki.apache.org - did not match any documents on a Google site search so it seems like you are seeing/using a custom GUI implementation / input.

The JMeter GUI would run on a 3rd machine.  So, from the perspective of the GUI, *Network Bandwidth Downlink* would seem to represent the JMeterEngine NIC ingress traffic and *Network Bandwidth Uplink* would seem to represent the JMeterEngine NIC egress traffic.